# We should Ex-[communicate] this tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[communicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/communicate) is sitting at 130 questions.

Almost half of these questions are about Python's [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subprocess) module, usually code using the `Popen.communicate` method.  Of those, the overwhelming majority are already tagged [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subprocess) and/or [popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/popen), but a few aren't, so this tag occasionally leads to mistagged questions.

The rest are about network communication, inter-process communication, and communication between threads, all of which have their own tags.

### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

As shown above, no.

### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? And is it unambiguous?

It is used to describe any situation where programs are communicating, which shines very little light on the content of the question, and is ambiguous.

### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

### Is the topic described even on-topic for the site?

Yes.  While "communicate" could describe inter-personal communication, for example, I haven't seen any questions like this.

Comment: Title suggestion: "We should ex-[communicate] this tag for mortal sins"

Comment: Without having looked at the questions, I'm going to speculate that at least half of them can be trivially closed with, "like the documentation says, don't use `Popen` when `run` will do".

Comment: edit to something like "python-communicate" which is pretty common for tags about something, where, the (idiotic) name of the proprietary item sounds like a commonplace word

Comment: @Fattie I think the [python] + [subprocess] + [popen] combination is enough for labeling these questions already, and those tags have a much wider audience.

Comment: Ugh, there's another tag called `communication` with 2400 questions and all of the same problems aside from the `Popen.communicate` questions.
usage: "Communication is the activity of conveying information."
I missed the forest for the trees.

Comment: you've truly found a disaster, @CraigWhite !

Comment: Tag [communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/communication).

Comment: What we have here is a failure to [communicate].

Comment: @IanCampbell Consider using `Pope.excommunicate` for that purpose.

Comment: Good find, first tag I've seen with "no usage guidance.". Any such tags, IMHO, should be impossible to create in the first place. We should at least be able to add a one line guidance when creating tags.